How to add List-Unsubscribe header to sendmail
I'm using sendmail with this format:
sendmail example@example.com
From: mydomain@mydomain.com
To: example@example.com
Subject: testing
testing.
.

Not sure where to add the list-unsubscribe header

There should be empty line between headers and message body


I'm using sendmail with this format

That doesn't really explain how you are invoking sendmail. I'm guessing you mean that you are invoking it from the shell and feeding the data via STDIN. Don't do that. There are lots of tools and libraries which will help with this. Assuming that you have some requirement for invoking this from the shell, you might consider using mutt. But using custom headers with Mutt needs a similar solution to sending to stdin of sendmail but using a template file.
The additional header can be anywhere in the header block, but by convention the first three headers are Subject, To and From in that order (headers are added to the top of the current message).
